# Dynamically adding a CSS file from an ASP.NET Server Control

Tags: asp.net, css, webforms

I have a custom control and I want to dynamically insert a link to a stylesheet.

Might not be the best solution of the year but it needs to be done. Any idea how to do it?

Everytime I try, Page.Header is null.

Comment: At what point during the page life cycle are you trying to access the Page.Header?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's how you would normally add a CSS programatically:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var link = new HtmlLink();
    link.Href = "~/styles/main.css";
    link.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    link.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    Page.Header.Controls.Add(link);
}
```

You might need to put a `runat="server"` in the `head` tag:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Add CSS example</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Got it. I was missing the Runat="Server" in the header tag of my masterpage. :)

Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't this be a problem if you added the control, say, 10 times on your page? Then the CSS file would be linked 10 times.

Comment: @Peter, yes I guess that would be problematic.

Answer (score 11):

To avoid the problem of multiple stylesheets when adding the control 10 times to the page, change the above code slightly:

```
string styleSheet = "stylesheetName.css";
if (this.Page.Header.FindControl(styleSheet) == null)
{
    HtmlLink cssLink = new HtmlLink();
    cssLink.ID = styleSheet;
    cssLink.Href = "~/styles/" + styleSheet;
    cssLink.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    cssLink.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(cssLink);
}
```

By giving the control an ID you can check if it already exists, and so ensure that you only add it the once.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamic css in head tag it wont work, you need to paste the css link tag in the body tag then it may work

Comment: exactly if you adding dynamic url, the it won't work in head tag

Answer (score 1):

I know this question have already accepted an answer.
I recently went through the same error.
The javascript/Css with <% %> tags from the head can give you error.
Removing ASP tags <% %> from head fixes this error.

I was getting the same error in a weird way, I had css files in master page, It used to work for the first page but on the second page after redirecting, I was getting error. So I removed the css link from head tag and pasted it at the end of form tag.

http://italez.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-calendarextender-e-strana-eccezione/